# My producer can create a topic, but data doesn't seem to be stored inside the broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

My producer can create a topic, but it doesn't seem to store any data inside a broker. I can check that the topic is created with  `kafka-topics` script.

When I tried to consume with `kafka-console-consumer`, it doesn't consume anything.    (I know `--from-beginning`.)

When I produced with `kafka-console-producer`, my consumer(`kafka-console-consumer`) can consume it right away. So there is something wrong with my java code.

And when I run my code with `localhost:9092`, it worked fine. And when I consume the topic with my consumer code, it was working properly. My producer works with Kafka server on my local machine but doesn't work with another Kafka server on remote machine.

**Code :**

```java
//this code is inside the main method
Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");  
        //When I used localhost, my consumer code consumes it fine. 
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.30:9092");        
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test5", "1111","jin1111");
        //topc is created, but consumer can't consume any data. 
        //I tried putting different values for key and value parameters but no avail.

        try {
            kafkaProducer.send(record);
            System.out.println("complete");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        }
           
        /*//try{
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord("test", Integer.toString(i), "message - " + i ));
        }*/
```

**My CLI (Putty) :**

[image]

**I want to see my consumer consuming when I run my java code.**  (Those data shown in the image are from the producer script.)

---

## update

After reading answers and comments, this is what I've tried so far. Still not consuming any messages. I think message produced in this code is not stored in the broker. I tried with the different server, too. The same problem. Topic was created, but no consumer exists in the consumer group list and can't consume. And no data can be consumed with consumer script.

I also tried permission change. (chown)  and tried with etc/hosts files. but no luck. I'll keep on trying until I solve this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.30:9092");        
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("linger.ms", "1");
        properties.put("batch.size", "16384");
        properties.put("request.timeout.ms", "30000");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test5", "1111","jin1111");
        System.out.println("1");
        try {
            kafkaProducer.send(record);
            //kafkaProducer.send(record).get();
            // implement Callback 
            System.out.println("complete");
            kafkaProducer.flush();
            System.out.println("flush completed");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.flush();
            System.out.println("another flush test");
            kafkaProducer.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        }       
}
```

When I run this in Eclipse, the console shows :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out. If you experienced similar problem, there are things you can do.

In your `server.properties`, uncomment these and put the ip and port.
(There seems to be a problem with the port, so I changed it.)

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.30:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.30:9093
```

(Before restarting your broker with your changed server.properties, you might want to clean all existing `log.dir`. Try this, if nothing works)

Some other things you might want to consider :

- change your `log.dir`.  Usually the default path is `tmp`, but sometimes there is a `noexec` setting, so  configure to a different location
- check your `etc/hosts`
- check your permission : And use `chown` and `chmod`
- change zookeeper port and kafka port if necessary.
- change broker.id

My working **producer** code :

```java
public class Producer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();            
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.30:9093");        
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test", "1","jin");

        try {           
            kafkaProducer.send(record);
            System.out.println("complete");                     
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        }              
    }   
}
```

working **Consumer** code:

```java
public class Consumer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.30:9093");
        props.put("group.id", "jin");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));

        try {
            while (true) {              

                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());          
                }                           
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
        }   
    }
}
```

**Console :**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To complete the ppatierno answer, you should call KafkaProducer.flush() before calling KafkaProducer.close(). This is a blocking call and will not return before all record got sent.

Yannick

Comment: Yes if the application is just a main sending a message and then exiting :) but I guess it's just a test for a long running application where this problem should not happen. Anyway Flush before close is a right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your main method exits and the application ends before the message is sent by the Kafka client.
The `send` method is not sync. The client buffers messages and send them after reaching a timeout named linger time (see linger.ms) or the buffer is filled to a specific size (see batch.size parameter for example). The default linger time is anyway 0.
So what your main method does is providing the message to the `send` method but then it exits and the underlying thread in the Kafka client isn't able to send the message.

Comment: Do I configure linger.ms and batch.size parameters in server.properties?

Comment: No this are not part of the broker configuration but of the client configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to check if data is stored in a Topic?  maybe with kafka-topics script? I tried  kafka-topics  --describe  but it doesn't tell anything about how much data, or any data in.

Comment: There is an overload of the send method which allows you to pass a callback. It's called when the message is got by the broker and provides you the topic, partition and offset where the message was stored.